# Stochastic process with constant information gain

Tags: stochastic-processes, entropy

For my research I am looking for a stochastic process that fulfills the following conditions.

1. The process takes values between 0 and 1, $X(t) \in [0,1]$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.
2. The process ends if it hits either 1 or 0. Denote this time by $T^*$.
3. If $X(t) = p$, then the probability that the process hits 1 (instead of/before hitting 0) is equal to $p$.
4. The expected remaining duration of the process at time $t$ is the binary entropy of $X(t)$, $E(T^*|X(t)=p) - t = -p \ln p - (1-p) \ln (1-p)$.
5. The process satisfies the Markov property.
6. The process is continuous.

If I understand it correctly, a Wiener process started somewhere between 0 and 1 and ending as soon as it hits a boundary only fulfills conditions 1, 2, 5, and 6. (Perhaps also 3 if parametrized correctly?) It certainly fails 4, though one can find a continuous transformation of the expected duration that makes it equal to the entropy.